# graphics.bf(img.image).s().p("xxx...") can't show image correctly

Tags: html5-canvas, createjs

When I use Toolkit for CreateJs for converting flash to html5, I always meet an annoying problem that the following code can't show the image correctly:

```
this.shape.graphics.bf(img.image49).s().p("EhcPBFNMAAAiKZMC4gAAAMAAACKZg");
```

I think this is caused by `p("EhcPBFNMAAAiKZMC4gAAAMAAACKZg")`, but I don't understand p-code. So anyone can help me to solve it?

[this is shown result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUGB3.png)

[this is the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbeES.png)

Comment: The `p()` method is encoded path instructions, however you can change it to actual API calls by visiting the publish preferences, and toggling the "Compact Shapes" option. Any chance you can post the FLA?

Comment: Thanks Lanny, I am first time to post question in stackoverflow.com. How to post the FLA? Here seem only to post image, html, javascript, and link. You can simply import any image to lib in Flash, convert it to shape, then drag it to stage. Use Toolkit for CreateJs to export it to html, you should see my same result.

Comment: alright, I can test with those steps. Sounds like it could be a publish issue with bitmap fills.

Comment: Did a quick test, and could not reproduce. On the latest Flash CC: http://playpen.createjs.com/Shape.fla

Comment: I believe that Toolkit for CreateJS did not support transforms in bitmap fills. This was added in Flash CC. If the transformation was exported, it would show up as the third param in the bitmap fill call. ex. `.bf(img.image49, "no-repeat", new createjs.Matrix2D(...));`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using a bitmap fill here? If you switch to just a bitmap instance it should export fine using Toolkit.

Comment: I don't have Flash CC. I don't know there is such code  bf(img.image49).s().p("EhcPBFNMAAAiKZMC4gAAAMAAACKZg") in your js file. You just check my code of js and html.

Comment: https://googledrive.com/host/0B818UxFZS7doOGpmYkJJNnFSUVU/image49.html

https://googledrive.com/host/0B818UxFZS7doOGpmYkJJNnFSUVU/image49.js

Comment: When using Toolkit for CreateJs to convert shape.fla to html5, it gives a waring: Bitmap fills will not be transformed in the output, and may render differently.   It means Toolkit for Js doesn't make sure its transformation is correct. I don't know Flash CC can make it right? If right, I have to upgrade to Flash CC version.

Comment: I have found out the parameters of Matrix2D in shape50.xml, and use  bf(img.image49, "no-repeat", new createjs.Matrix2D(...)) to replace p-code , but don't show anything, why? how to use function beginBitmapFill()?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off 'Compact shapes' options while publish to createjs. Then you will see what `p("EhcPBFNMAAAiKZMC4gAAAMAAACKZg")` is.

Comment: moveTo(...).lineTo(...).lineTo(...).lineTo(...).closePath(); It seems render the image to 4 corners of square.

Comment: Note that Flash export will use individual `moveTo/LineTo` commands when you just use a normal shape. It will use `drawRect` if you use a Rectangle primitive.

Comment: Hi Lanny, could you use .bf(img.image49, "no-repeat", new createjs.Matrix2D(...)) to replace .bf(img.image49).p('EhcPBFNMAAAiKZMC4gAAAMAAACKZg') ?